# How to share video using linked in REST API?

Tags: php, rest, api, video, linkedin-api

I am using linked in REST API for share on user's wall. I have referred this https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin. It is working fine with text and images. But there is no option to share video. Any help would be great.